# Laravel 4 model not found

Tags: php, model, frameworks, laravel

I have this model file:

\app\models\Recipe.php

```
<? php

class Recipe extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'recipes';
}
```

and this is my Controller:

```
<?php
class IndexController extends BaseController {

    public function showIndex()
    {
        $recipes = Recipe::all();
    return View::make('index',array('recipes' => $recipes));
    }

}
```

When i try to call the page I get this error message:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Recipe' not found
```

I also executed

```
composer dump-autoload
```

any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Is really your source code as `<? php` and not `<?php` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Recipe.php is directly copied and pasted.

```
<? php 
   class Recipe extends Eloquent{
      protected $table = 'recipes';
   }
```

Then it is broken because the PHP tag is wrong. It needs to be `<?php` and not `<? php` It's just reading as a file instead of a php file.

Comment: ouch... sorry about that